# JavaScript: To iterate through div class and return the desired text

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to write a javascript code to find the text in a number of divs with the same id's and it has its own unique class. Can someone please help me out?

Below is how the HTML from the page looks like.

```
<div class="errorMessage">
To Continue, address the following errors:
<br><br>
<div>               
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="errorFlag">
Select a business type.<br>         
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="errorFlag">
Professional Title required<br>
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="errorFlag">
Enter a 10-digit phone number<br>                               
</div>
<div class="clearBoth">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to iterate through this HTML page and would like to return the 'Enter a 10-digit phone number' text.

```
{
onload = function(){
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++)
{
    if (divs[i].innerHTML.substr('Enter a 10-digit phone number')>=0)
 document.getElementById("errorFlag").innerHTML=divs[i].innerHTML
//I am not able to figure out what I should be doing here? 
}                   
}
```

Comment: id's should be unique.  use a class if you need to repeat.

Comment: The arguments to `substr` are a starting position and length, not a string. I think you meant to use `indexOf`.

Comment: Another problem: `<input>` elements don't have `innerHTML`. Why are you trying to set this?

Comment: @dave Could you tell me how I could use a class. And id's are not unique. That is how it is present on the page.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks Barmar. Yes I was thinking of using indexof. And would you know how I could possibly get that text where the id's are non-unique ?

Comment: The page has so many problems with it. Why do you have "Enter ..." prompts next to hidden inputs?